# Is there a way to make grouped lines in a plotly plot?

Tags: plotly, julia

i'm new to julia and very new at Plotly, so i'm strugling to get plots as I want.

Lets say I have some lists I want to plot but i would like to make it in group form so I can activate or deactivate this plots at same time:

```
x1_group1 = [-2,2,3]
y1_group1 = [3,2,-2]
x2_group1 = [-1,1]
y2_group1 = [0,0]

x1_group2 = [1,2]
y1_group2 = [1,3]


p1 = scatter(x=x1_group1,y=y1_group1)
p2 = scatter(x=x2_group1,y=y2_group1)
p3 = scatter(x=x1_group2,y=y1_group2)

plot([p1,p2,p3])
```

That's what i'm currently doing but I would like to get all lines in one plot but divided by groups, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I have no experience with julia, but there is an example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/julia/legend/#grouped-legend-items) about the ability to group legends.

Comment: I really searched a lot and didn't find this example. Thanks Sorry for the dumb question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
using PlotlyJS

x1_group1 = [-2,2,3]
y1_group1 = [3,2,-2]
x2_group1 = [-1,1]
y2_group1 = [0,0]

x1_group2 = [1,2]
y1_group2 = [1,3]

p1 = scatter(
    x=x1_group1,
    y=y1_group1,
    legendgroup="group1",
    legendgrouptitle_text="1st Group",
    name="1st legend group",
    mode="lines"
)

p2 = scatter(
    x=x2_group1,
    y=y2_group1,
    legendgroup="group1",
    name="1st legend group",
    mode="lines"
)

p3 = scatter(
    x=x1_group2,
    y=y1_group2,
    legendgroup="group2",
    legendgrouptitle_text="1st Group",
    name="2nd legend group",
    mode="lines"
)

plot([p1, p2, p3])
```

Output:

[image]